# Getting an error upon deactivating user due to "receiving cases or notifications as part of your case assignment/escalation rules."

Tags: case, error, user, deactivate, escalation

I am getting the following error upon attempting user deactivation:

You cannot deactivate this user.
You cannot deactivate a user who is receiving cases or notifications as part of your case assignment/escalation rules. 
Click [here](/ui/setup/Setup?setupid=Case) to view your case assignment / escalation rules.

I have changed the Automated User's to myself from this user, but this person worked on pretty much everything in this org prior to me and I can't seem to find where else he's being used. Any ideas?

Update**

I tried to change this user to a Standard User from Administrator and I got the following error:

Error: This user, as the Default Lead Creator, must have the "Modify All Data" and "Send Email" permissions. Select a profile or assign a permission set with these permissions enabled.

BUT the thing is, I changed Default Lead Creator to myself prior to attempting this.

Comment: did you check the case assignment rules and all case escalation rules?
Also, try freezing the account first and then look at deactivating the user so that you still have time to make changes and user no longer has access

Comment: The user is now frozen. There is a Case Assignment rule, the user in question is the creator, but the user is not used in the rule itself. When deactivate that rule and try to deactivate the user, I still get the same error.

Comment: created by should not be a problem. Can you check for any inactive rules where the user is referenced? You need to remove user from inactive rules too

Comment: So, the user was in a hierarchy Role. I just took him our of that role and that enabled me to change the user and make him a Standard User. But, when I try to deactivate, I still get the error mentioned in the beginning, assignment/escalation rules.

Comment: **Can you check for any inactive case assignment rules where the user is referenced? You need to remove user from inactive rules too ?**

Comment: I deleted the inactive Case Assignment Rules and was able to deactivate the user. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove user from all case assignment rules, both active and inactive.